# Remove [caption][/caption] from am string

Tags: php, regex, php-5.3

Suppose that I have the string

```
test [caption id="attachment_13399" align="alignleft" width="240"]<img class="img" src="test.jpg" alt="Test Image" width="240" height="270" /> Test remove capture[/caption] end test
```

I need after preg_replace to show only : `test end test`

But I get `test Test remove capture end test`.

My regex is : `$text = preg_replace('/\[.*?\]/', '', $a_record['content'])`

Can you help me please ? Thx in advance and sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
/\\[caption.*?\\].*\\[.caption\\]/
```

This will remove everything that's between `[caption]` and `[/caption]`